# Fabricjs is not working on ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have installed gem 'fabricjs-rails', '~> 2.0.0'. I have simple code here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function () {
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', { left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas.add(text);
});
```

But it is not working in my Ruby on Rails project.

Comment: What happened to your project? Is the canvas displayed?